# Splitting up Code into Multiple Files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker

I know this has been asked a billion times before, but I'm still having trouble.

I began with one `main.cpp` file that contained all of my code. Say it looked like this:

```
int a = 0;
void foo() {
    a+1;
}

void bar() {
    a+2;
}

int main() {
    foo();
    bar();
    a + 3;
}
```

Now I want to split up this code into multiple files for easier management. I would like to only have one header, `header.h`, and three `.cpp` files: `main.cpp`, `foo.cpp`, and `bar.cpp`.

ATM, this is what I have:

```
//header.h
int a = 0;
void foo();
void bar();
```

.

```
//foo.cpp
#include "header.h"
void foo() {a+1;}
```

.

```
//bar.cpp
#include "header.h"
void bar() {a+2;}
```

.

```
//main.cpp
#include "header.h"
int main() {
    foo();
    bar();
    a + 3;
}
```

Unfortunately, the linker has been complaining that I've defined `a` multiple times. I've tried using `#ifdef`, but that only guards against redefining in the same file, correct? How can I make this work?

EDIT: Modified the question, I just realized that it is the variables that have been defined multiple times, not the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the bigger problem is you are *implementing* something in a *header* file. The problem is when you include the header into more than one object file, you will run into problem at linker time. Don't do it.

Use a [define](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/teas0593%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for this sort of thing. They difference is that a `define`, being a preprocessor macro, doesn't create any object code by itself, and won't create any symbols. There are advantages to declaring some sort of `const` type instead of a `define`, but I think not having to worry about symbol collisions at link time is a bigger benefit.

Your header file needs [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), as well

Comment: OK, I got it now. I `#define`d `definitions` to `int a = 0`, then in my `main.cpp`, included `definitions` at the top, right after my headers. Is this proper style?

Comment: Well, it depends. Are the defines necessary for some functionality your are supplying in the header? If they go hand-in-hand, they should be in the header. If the definition is merely some global magic value that only makes sense in the context of your main program, I'd consider using a `const int`, defined in your main.cpp, instead of a `define`. Some people make a header specifically including global definitions, which is definitely more scalable.

Comment: I prefer to put the variable definitions in my `header.h` if I can, just so when I add a new global variable, I can add it in only one file without having to switch back and forth between two files.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that. You might consider a more descriptive name than header.h, though :)

Comment: Yeah, in my actual file, I used better names. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -3):

```
//header.h
void foo();
void bar();
```

should be

```
extern void foo();
extern void bar();
```